# How to connect weight scale machine to a webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have build a web application to calculate weight of product,
the application is build using "php, javascript & ajax" and it run in xampp server, now my client want me to attach the weight scale machine to the application so that the weight of the product would directly inserted in the appplication. 
plzz tell me what should is do? 
guide me with some codes or any third party software.
i just want the weight to be displayed on my web page.

Comment: at the current process, the user needs to input the weight of product and the application calculates the net weight and the packing weight.

Comment: does the weight scale machine has any interface? can you share some more information about the device?

Comment: yes the machine do have the interfaceand it can also be connected to the computer with the help of windows inbuild application name "hyperterminal " the below link will show the image and model no of the machine

Comment: http://uniconelectronics.com/electronics-weighing-scale.html

Comment: model no.:-  UC 7008/2

Comment: RS232 port is available on the machine

Comment: all i want is to display the weight on my web page.  if possible tell me the proper method of doing it like what application should i use or any sample codes to connect that machine with my web page.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to attach the weight scale machine as an human interface device (HID) you might be able to configure it, so that the weight is inserted as keyboard input. That's the same way most barcode scanners work.

If this is not possible you need to create a native app that interfaces with the machine. You can then put the weight in the clipboard or add it to the keyboard buffer like mentioned in the first paragraph.

Embedding native code directly into your web page requires a browser extension. A few years ago this would have been done as an ActiveX Control which only works in Internet Explorer.

Those are the possibilites you have. Thre route to take depends largely on your environment. What interfaces are supported by the machine, what OS has the computer that is connected to the machine. What programming tools are available. ...

Comment: is there no one to ans. this question ??

Comment: RS232 is serial communication. You need a native app to access a serial interface. If the PHP server is installed on the the same machine, the weighting scale is connected to, you might be able to use the direct IO extension of PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php for details